# Javascript setAttribute returning nothing

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm trying to set an image as a background, and the image source is pulled from a variable.  I've tried different methods from the setAttribute to src= ect.  Can you guys tell me what i'm missing?

Here is my html code i'm trying to set the image too i've tried with the img tag not having the src in the tag to start as well still nothing:

```
    <body onload = "mapThing()">
        <img id = "elephant" src=''>
        <canvas id="processing"></canvas>
    </body>
```

here is the function that has the setAtt elements in it:

```
   function mapThing(){
    mapUrl = getValue("urlValue");
    var backImg = parseUrl(mapUrl);
    console.log(backImg);
    function setBack(){
    document.getElementById('elephant').setAttribute('backImg', 'src');
   }
    setBack();
   }
```

the backImage is a url in the form of:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x600&location=40.736315,-73.992243&fov=75&heading=23.58&pitch=10

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Set the background image or set some arbitrary attribute that you'll use later?

Answer (score 4):

You have backImages between quotes in [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute). 
And also have the parameters inverted.Try removing them and change parameter order:

```
document.getElementById('elephant').setAttribute('src',backImg);
```

Comment: hah of course it was something dumb like that ahhhhhh.  First time putting javascript into a website hah.  Was a late night.  Thx it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following? You are using the setAttribute method wrong.

```
document.getElementById('elephant').style.backgroundImage = backImg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simple `src` is valid attribute of `<img/>` element, you can access as `Object`, see below

```
document.getElementById('elephant').src = backImg;
```